# PHP : Regex to extract data from web url

Tags: javascript, php, html, regex

I am receiving URL from an application as post data.

The URL has a signature : //abc.com/name?q=123456.

I want to extract name from the URL using regex ( Regular Expression )
How do I do that?

Comment: Short answer is don't. Use this instead: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php and get the `path` component.

Answer (score -1):

Best method is parsing url, but if you need regex to extract `name` :

```
/.+\/([^\?]+?)(\?|$)/gm
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Lwr3l7/1)

Note: this regex pattern match whole url, but captures `name` that you want in Group 1.